# Is it possible to create a PushEvent with more than one commit?

Tags: github-api

I'm using this [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/tleyden/464156ab3a403d0a977b682b5847f9a8#file-end_to_end_integration_test-go-L415-L540) to create commits via the github API using go-github, and it's not working as planned.

I'm trying to create a single push event that contains all 26 commits, but instead it's creating 26 push events, each of which contains a single commit.  If you're wondering "why?", it's because I'm trying to recreate a particular scenario to validate some behavior.

Is this limitation due to the "connected/online" nature of the Github API?  Would I need to have a local github repo checkout and do the commits and pushes via "git commit" and "git push"?  (either cli or libgit bindings)

Comment: I was able to hack it by adding a delay between commits, pushing to another branch, and then adding a merge commit to merge that branch to the master branch: check out the  [updated code snippet](https://gist.github.com/tleyden/ddbe9e0a38ee875acf90b3caaac5a581#file-end_to_end_integration_test-go-L415-L562).  Will try to post a cleaner solution at some point.